# How to write about this kind of situation?

Tags: sentence-construction, expressions, american-english

I've tried hard for my physical test to be able to pass every items,   Unfortunately I had a bad performance and in conquence, very bad  results in my physical examinations,  now I have to say about my results to one of my teacher , and my English is not good enough too!  It's really hard for me to write about my terrible grade that I've get. You know, It's kind of embarrassing.

How should I write about it? What expression I can use to show my shame and embarrassed? Please help me!

Is this statement is grammatically true?

> To tell the truth, My grades is kind of embarrassing, I've tried really hard but I couldn't pass the practical exam. I'm really sorry!

Answer (score 1):

> Is this statement is grammatically true?
>
> To tell the truth, My grades is kind of embarrassing, I've tried really hard but I couldn't pass the practical exam. I'm really sorry!

It is not grammatically correct, because your verb form (`is`) is singular, but `grades` is plural. This is an easy fix: Just change it to 'My grades are kind of embarrassing'.

There is another minor issue with the second part. I would change `I've` to `I` to be more idiomatic.

Comment: thanks, is this statement good? Is there better expression?

Comment: "To tell the truth, my grades are kind of embarrassing. I tried really hard but I couldn't pass the practical exam. I'm really sorry!" is absolutely fine.